# RegEx pattern selects the proper substring but throws error when running macro vba

Tags: regex, vba, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

I am trying to remove everything after the comma `,` preceded by a `[` (an open bracket) and `?` (a question mark) in both strings with a regular expression.

I have input like:

`Together, Let's End Their War: Promoting a Culture of Health among Veterans on the Gulf - How strongly do you value your relationship with [Field-2]?`

and

`Together, Let's End Their War: Promoting a Culture of Health among Veterans on the Gulf - During the Clinical Scholars Program, with [Field-2], have you partnered new project(s) other than your team's Wicked Problem Impact Project?`

So I want to remove the `?` in the first string and the following in the second string

`, have you partnered new project(s) other than your team's Wicked Problem Impact Project?`

I want to end up with

`Together, Let's End Their War: Promoting a Culture of Health among Veterans on the Gulf - How strongly do you value your relationship with [Field-2]`

and

`Together, Let's End Their War: Promoting a Culture of Health among Veterans on the Gulf - During the Clinical Scholars Program, with [Field-2]`

I have
`(?<=]),\s*([^,])+|\?`

The pattern seems to be capturing what I want

but when I run my macro I get `Method 'Replace' of object 'IRegEep2' failed`

https://regex101.com/r/c9lDYD/1

I have run many other regex patterns with my macro with no issue so not sure what the problem is.

```
Sub findReplace()
Dim outArray As Variant
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

  Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(?<=]),\s*([^,])+|\?"
  Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
        
  With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
 End With
    
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Helper_1Filted")

 With ws.Range("K1:K50")
    
      outArray = .value
      For i = 1 To UBound(outArray, 1)
          outArray(i, 1) = regEx.Replace(outArray(i, 1), strReplace)
      Next i
        
      .value = outArray
        
  End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the lookbehind is not supported in vba, but if the question mark should come after matching a comma and a part between square brackets you can use a capture group without an alternation `|`.

When using an alternation `|` the question mark will be matched anywhere in the string.

You might use a capture group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^`

In the replacement use group 1 `$1`

```
(,[^\]\[,]*\[[^\]\[]*])[^?]*\?
```

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `,` Match a comma
  - `[^\]\[,]*` Match 0+ times any char except a comma or `[` or `]`
  - `\[[^\]\[]*]` Match from `[...]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^?]*` Match 0+ times any char except a question mark
- `\?` Match the question mark

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U5Eg37/1)

Or a shorter version with an optional capture group:

```
(\])(?:,\s*[^,]+)?\?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/21pdsz/1)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know VBA does not support `lookbehind `

Answer (score 0):

After checking, it maybe the current VBA regex library 5.5 does not support the call back function in your code, as there is warning when i do the testing

```
?<=]
```

By amend it abit, it work by replace the question mark in your example, although other sentence I may not 100% sure, I only change the beginning part, fyi.

```
(^]),\s*([^,])+|\?
```